# Is the ball $\mathcal{B}_r(X)\triangleq\{Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}:\|Y-X\|<r\} $ a convex set?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-geometry

Let $r>0$ and $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Let $\|A\|$ denote any matrix norm of $A$. Is the ball $\mathcal{B}_r(X)\triangleq\{Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}:\|Y-X\|<r\} $ a convex set? How can I prove or disprove that?

---

I know that $\mathcal{B}_r(X)$ is convex if and only if for all $A,B\in\mathcal{B}_r(X)$, and all $\alpha\in[0,1]$,
$$\|\alpha A+(1-\alpha)B-X\|< r.$$

Comment: Yes, it is convex - go with the definition and use properties of the norm. It works for any norm. Your definition of convexity is messed up though.

Comment: OK, you fixed it. Now $\|\alpha A+(1-\alpha B)-X\| = \|\alpha(A-X)+(1-\alpha)(B-X)\|\leq|\alpha|\|A-X\|+|1-\alpha|\|B-X\|<\alpha\|A-X\|+(1-\alpha)\|B-X\|<r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a loss of generality, center the ball around zero. Then take $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ with $||x||,||y||< r$. Then for $\lambda\in[0,1]$
we have 
$$
||\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y||\\
\stackrel{\text{triangle ineq.}}{\leq}
||\lambda x||+||(1-\lambda)y||\\
\stackrel{\text{homogeneity}}{=}\lambda|| x||+(1-\lambda)||y||\\
<\lambda r+(1-\lambda)r=r
$$

Comment: That proves convexity of the *closed* ball, not the open ball as requested by the OP. Moreover, this is just the same as my proof above?

Comment: indeed, I will change the inequalities to strict ones. Yes, it is hard to get too creative with this proof